# A problem on rationals limit point etc.

Tags: real-analysis

$B=\cup_n(r_n - 2 ^ {-n-2}, r_n + 2 ^ {-n-2})$ where $r_1, r_2, \dots$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $(0,1]$. I want to understand the set $(0,1]-B$ like limit point of that set. Hint enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to be an example to make you realize that some weird things can happen with infinite sets - even sets we think we understand, like unit interval.

The main thing about $B$ is that it contains all the rationals in $(0,1]$.  Since the rationals are a dense subset of $(0,1]$, this means that every element of $(0,1]$ is expressible as the limit point of elements on $B$.

The measure of $B$, on the other hand, is quite small. The $n$th open interval in the construction of $B$ has length $2^{-n-1}$, which means that by subadditivity, the measure of $B$, denoted $\lambda(B)$ satisfies:
$$\lambda(B)\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n-1}=\frac{1}{2}.$$ 
It follows immediately that $\lambda((0,1]\setminus B)\geq \frac{1}{2}$.
(It is also easy to see that a set with similar properties can be found with an arbitrarily small measure.)

Finally, since $B$ is defined as a union of open intervals, it follows that $B$ is open, and that $(0,1]\setminus B$ is closed.

So, $(0,1]\setminus B$ is a largish set in $(0,1]$ (and can be made arbitrarily large by making the open intervals used in the construction of $B$ smaller). It is a closed set.  It contains only irrational numbers, which means it is totally disconnected.  And it lies in the closure of $B$.

Does this make the set easier to understand?

Comment: I want to prove that if $(0,1]-B \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$ ($I_k$'s are half-open interval) then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|I_k|$ is at least some positive number. I want to do it using the definition of negligibility and without notion of "measure".

Comment: Well since $(0,1]\setminus B$ is closed (its complement is open), and since it contains no non-empty open intervals (since every non-empty open interval contains a rational number), it follows that it is nowhere dense, and hence a negligible set. Is that what you wanted?  What are the $I_{k}$s?

Comment: no,it is not a negligible set. I want to prove that.

Comment: Moreover, a nowhere dense set may or may not be negligible.

Comment: $B$ is the union of open sets, and so is open. The complement of $B$ is therefore closed. Furthermore, $B$ contains all the rational numbers.  Since every non-empty open interval contains at least one rational number, the complement of $B$ cannot contain any rational numbers and so cannot contain non-empty open intervals. So, $\left(\overline{(0,1]\setminus B}\right)^{\circ}= ((0,1]\setminus B)^{\circ}=\emptyset$.  The complement of $B$ is therefore nowhere dense.  Since all nowhere dense sets are negligible, it must be true that the complement of $B$ is negligible.

Comment: A set is negligible if it is the union of a countable family of nowhere dense sets.  A family of one is countable, so nowhere dense sets are negligible.

Comment: negligibility has some connection with measure. a set is negligible iff it has measure zero. But, this sets have measure at least $\frac{1}{2}$. A set is negligible if it can be covered by countable union of half-open intervals such that the sum of length of the intervals can be made arbitrarily small. your definition is of "first category" according to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12774/discussion-between-unwisdom-and-aaaaaa)